# Updating a 500 million row mysql table

Tags: mysql

So i have a mysql table with ~15 columns and around 500 million rows (gets truncated to only contain information for the last 30 days).

I just was tasked with updating this table with a new column. The column will come from another table that i will join on the update under the constraint that a column on the original table rlike a a column on another table.

The update query is as follows:

update termination t join dialplan d on t.ip rlike d.ip set t.LCR = d.LCR where t.proxy = d.proxy;

I have ran this update for over 5 hours and it still is not yet finished. I was wondering if there is a way to speed up this update? The used columns on both the tables are indexed.

Let me know if any other information is required. Thank you.

Comment: `rlike` is probably forcing a full table scan, so indexes won't matter.

Comment: Adding a new column or updating rows?

Comment: Updating a just added new column where everything is null

Comment: Have you tried `ON t.proxy = d.proxy AND t.ip rlike d.ip` (instead of a WHERE) with a compound index on `proxy, ip` (in that order)?

Comment: @Uueerdo I actually never thought about that, I assumed that join and where were relatively the same (after googling now I know that they are not). I will do that and see what happens and keep this thread update. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why rlike!?!?!?!?

Comment: The column d.ip contains regex of IPs

Comment: @MichaelJC You may or may not see a difference from moving the condition from the WHERE to the ON; while WHERE is logically applied after the JOIN is performed, MySQL is pretty good about using its conditions early if they can safely narrow the rows to be analyzed for joining. My hypothesis of potential performance gain is from the possibility that putting the two conditions together may increase the likelihood MySQL takes advantage of the suggested compound index.

Comment: It looks like it didn't make a difference. I tried doing it over night and it actually failed.